# Distribution of a random variable to the power of 3

Tags: probability-distributions

I have to answer the following question: $X$ has a uniform distribution between 0 and 1. What is the distribution of $X^3$?

I'm not looking for an answer, just want to know how I should begin to answer the question.

Now the pdf is simply:

$f(x)=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1, &\mbox{if } 0\leq x \leq1 \\
  0, & \mbox{otherwise}
 \end{array}
\right.$

So do I simply substitute $x$ with $x^3$ and rearrange the inequalities?

Thanks

Comment: One way would be to compute the cdf for $X^3$ and differentiate to find the pdf.

Comment: How would I compute the CDF for $X^3$? By computing CDF for $X$ and then substituting $x^3$ for $x$?

Comment: You could also apply a one to one transformation.

Comment: @Vlad: Directly from the definition $F(t) = P(X^3\le t) = P(X\le \sqrt[3] t) = \cdots$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: You mean $F(t)$? Normally variable names shouldn't matter but you didn't define $f$, in which case upper case is usually for CDF.

Comment: @user21820: Yes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic problem in "transformations"  Since the transformation is 1-1 ($x^3$ is one-to-one on $[0,1]$) the formula is $F_{g(X)}(x)=F_X(g^{-1}(x))$ where $F$ is the cumulative distribution (which in this case is just $F_X(x)=x$).  So substitute $\sqrt[3]{x}$ into that.  Then take the derivative to get the density function.

Comment: So pdf of $X^3$ is $f(x)=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac 1 3 x^-\frac{2}{3}, &\mbox{if } 0\leq x \leq1 \\
  0, & \mbox{otherwise}
 \end{array}
\right.$ The questions asks "What is the distribution of $X^3$?" - Is there a name for a distribution with this pdf? Because it doesn't seem to ring a bell for me...